# How to include a makefile gracefully even if nonexistent

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In (GNU) make how can I include additional makefiles (which might pre-set some variables) at the beginning of a (master) makefile  without an interrupting error message when the additional makefiles not exist?

I tried at the top of the makefile

```
include *.make
```

in order to override defaults like

```
main ?= main.md
DEPS ?= template.tpl
```

However, I do get the error:

```
Makefile:4: *.make: No such file or directory
```

probably because at the beginning of the makefile only definitions are allowed,not commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`sinclude` or equivalent `-include` (silent include) directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html):

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
sinclude *.make

all:
        echo foo

$ ls *.make
ls: *.make: No such file or directory
$ make -f GNUmakefile
echo foo
foo
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `wildcard` function which expands to the empty string if no files match:

```
include $(wildcard *.make)
```